# ORA-00604. I create connection pool and I trying to ping in glassfish

Tags: oracle, glassfish

I create Connection pool with this parameters:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

I try to ping in glassfish web-interface and I have got this exceprion:

> Ping Connection Pool failed for MyPool.
> Connection could not be allocated because: ORA-00604: error occurred
> at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or
> invalid environment specified  Please check the server.log for more
> details. An error has occurred Ping Connection Pool failed for MyPool.
> Connection could not be allocated because: ORA-00604: error occurred
> at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or
> invalid environment specified Please check the server.log for more
> details.

I add ojdbc6.jar(download from official oracle web site) in C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext (I have Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2)

Answer (score 0):

1) Please try by changing : Resource Type to javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource and Database driver vender to oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource

2) Try again a Ping